# What is boundary layer tripping?

Tags: lift, drag, fluid-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I came across the term "Boundary layer tripping" but I can't really underastand it. After searching on internet I cannot find any video or an image explaining that concept. Could you please explain what is "Boundary Layer tripping" with some figures/illustrations if possible?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: would [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32557/how-do-blow-holes-compare-to-other-means-of-tripping-the-boundary-layer/32562#32562) help to answer your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tripping the boundary layer refers to the action of artificially transitioning a laminar boundary layer into a turbulent one. It can happen intentionally (via [turbulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulator)) or unintentionally (via imperfect aero-smoothness, such as rivets, bolts, counter-sinks). At the point of boundary layer tripping, the surface protrusion destabilizes the laminar boundary layer and causes the transition to occur earlier than via natural [Tollmien-Schlichting instability](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74776/can-transition-on-an-airfoil-occur-without-prior-separation/74845#74845).

The following is an example of a [turbulator tape](https://www.hyperflight.co.uk/products.asp?code=F-RMXTT1&name=turbulator-tape). It is attached spanwise along the surface of the wing (facing flat against the surface) at the desired chord-wise location where the laminar-turbulent transition is to take place:

[image: Turbulator tape]

Since turbulent boundary layer has [higher skin-friction drag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70852/why-do-wings-prefer-laminar-flow-if-cd-is-lower-for-turbulent-flows) than a laminar one of the same Reynolds number, unintentional boundary layer tripping is undesired. That's why wing surfaces must be made flush and smooth. At the same time, since a turbulent boundary layer is much better at [resisting flow separation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70852/why-do-wings-prefer-laminar-flow-if-cd-is-lower-for-turbulent-flows) than a laminar boundary layer, tripping the boundary layer can be used to improve stability & control at high angle of attack at the expense of increased skin-friction drag.

Comment: You might want to note that the tape is applied flat to the surface, not standing up on edge like in the photo!  If I hadn't seen it before on gliders I would be mis-led by the photo.  Thanks!

Comment: @quietflyer Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Your zig-zag tape in the picture is merely destabilizing the boundary layer so it will transition downstream without a big separation bubble. Direct tripping is achieved with a trip wire or with [dimple tape](https://www.siebert.aero/images/product_images/super_images/42937_Noppenband_transp_10mm_2014120.jpg). And at high lift coefficient tripping is indeed used to **lower** drag by avoiding a lengthy separation bubble.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Agreed